# AWS CodeDeploy with two listeners

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-alb

I have an application load balancer with two listeners ( 80 and 443 ) and I want use CodeDeploy to deploy my fargate container.
I cannot redirect http traffic to https...

With CodeDeploy I can set up only one listeners in the prod_traffic_route, right?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy is an agent-based tool, usually used to deploy applications packages.

For deploying containers you're better using CodePipeline to build the docker image and deploy it to Fargate.

Take a look at this post:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/build-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-for-your-container-images-with-amazon-ecr-as-source/